# WinSCP (Far/NetBox) может ли использовать ключи ssh-2?

Tags: ssh-key, winscp, far-manager

При попытке соединения с авторизацией по ключу через WinSCP и Far/NetBox с узлом (OLES9), уже не поддерживающим по-умолчанию rsa-sha, соединение отклоняется:

```
sshd[2419]: userauth_pubkey: key type ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms [preauth]
```

При использовании этого же приватного ключа в PuTTY или MobaXterm- соединение успешное:

```
sshd[2421]: Accepted publickey for amk from 192.168.1.2 port 57969 ssh2: RSA SHA256:MJO...
```

Можно ли WinSCP принудительно заставить использовать SSH-2 ?

PS Добавить на сервере разрешение старого алгоритма "PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa" как решение не рассматривается.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/1813424/213663

Answer (score 2):

Вышла новая версия, с ней подключение успешно проходит!

`Accepted publickey ... ssh2: ...`

[24.2.2.590] - 2024-02-20
https://nightly.link/michaellukashov/Far-NetBox/workflows/release/main?preview